# How to enable validation of select option hide/show div-input only when it selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select option box that when I select it, a div-input appear. The problem that when I put validation on the this div-input, and when i submit even when it hide, it require me to validate it, thus giving me error msg.

How to do enable validation for this input field only when if it appear?

**PHP**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inquiry_type">Subject *: </label>
<select name="type" id="inquiry_type" class="form-control">
     <option value="0">Please Select</option>
     <option value="test1">test1</option>
   <option value="test2">test2</option>
   <option value="others">Other...</option> //div-input appear when sel
 </select>
</div>

 <div id="other_subj" class="form-group">
    <label for="other_msg_subj">Input Subject Title *: </label>
       <input type="text" id="other_msg_subj" class="form-control" name="other_msg_subj" placeholder="Enter Subject Title" required/>
</div>
```

**JQUERY** for hide/show

```
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#other_subj').hide();
    $('#inquiry_type').change(function(){
        if($('#inquiry_type').val() === 'others') {
            $('#other_subj').show();
        } else {
            $('#other_subj').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```
var inquiry_other_subj = document.getElementById("other_msg_subj").value;

 ...
 } else if (!inquiry_other_subj.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z ]).{5,20}$/)) {

   alert("Need to enter a proper inquiry title containing only letter!"); // I want this to be active only when the div is shown

 } else {

var parameters="...+"&other_msg_subj="+inquiry_other_subj;
```

**PHP validation**

```
//Same for this php validation
...
else if(!preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['other_msg_subj'])){

    echo "Please enter a valid message subject title!";
    exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help.

in **JQUERY**:

Validate only if `others` is selected.

```
var inquiry_type = $('#inquiry_type').val();
else if (inquiry_type === 'others' && !inquiry_other_subj.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z ]).{5,20}$/)) {
   alert("Need to enter a proper inquiry title containing only letter!");
 }
```

Add the `other_msg_subj`parameter in the variable `parameters` only if `others` is selected.

```
var parameters = "......"; //Other parameters
if(inquiry_type == "others")
{
     parameters = parameters + "&other_msg_subj="+inquiry_other_subj;
}
```

in **PHP**:

Check if only the parameter is present

```
else if(!isset($_POST['other_msg_subj']) && !preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['other_msg_subj']))
{
    echo "Please enter a valid message subject title!";
    exit();
}
```

Also (Just a suggestion) you can simplify the **JQUERY** code :

`show/hide` as `toggle(true/false)`
`true = show(), false = hide()`

```
$(function() {
    $('#other_subj').hide();
    $('#inquiry_type').change(function(){
        var display = $('#inquiry_type').val() === 'others';
        $('#other_subj').toggle(display);
    });
});
```

Comment: verify if the code work, also shouldn't the php be isset($_POST['other_msg_subj']) && instead of !isset($_POST['other_msg_subj']) &&

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to disable the input when it's hidden to prevent sending it's data to the server:

```
$(function() {
    $('#other_subj').hide();
    $('#inquiry_type').change(function(){
        if($('#inquiry_type').val() === 'others') {
            $('#other_msg_subj').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#other_subj').show();
        } else {
            $('#other_msg_subj').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#other_subj').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And you need to do a check before validating:

**On Javascript side:**

```
else if (
    $("#other_msg_subj").is(":visible") &&
    !inquiry_other_subj.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z ]).{5,20}$/)) {
```

**On PHP side:**

```
else if(isset($_POST['other_msg_subj']) && 
    !preg_match ('%^[A-Za-z\.\' \-]{2,30}$%', $_POST['other_msg_subj'])){
```